# Remove similar items from a list

Tags: python

I have a list of words (nearly 7 items) and I want to remove items who are nearly identical to the other words (ie if my word is 'Agency Account Bank Agreement' I want to remove words like 'Agency Account Bank Agreement Pursuant').

To estimate if a word is close to another word I used the Jaro Distance from the jellyfish package in Python.

And my current code is:

```
corpus3 = ['Agency Account Bank Agreement', 'Agent', 'Agency Account Bank Agreement Pursuant',
       'Agency Account Bank Agreement Notwithstanding', 'Agents', 'Agent', 'Reinvestment Period']
threshold = 0,85
for a, b in itertools.combinations(corpus3, 2):
    if len(a.split()) >= 2 or len(b.split()) >= 2:               
        jf = jellyfish.jaro_distance(a, b)
        if jf > threshold:
            if a in new_corpus and b in new_corpus:                
                continue
            else:
                if len(a.strip()) < len(b.strip()):
                    kw = a
                    if not new_corpus:
                        new_corpus.append(a)
                    else:    
                        for item in new_corpus:
                            jf = jellyfish.jaro_distance(kw, item)
                            if jf < threshold:
                                new_corpus.append(kw)
```

And this is what I want at the end:

```
new_corpus = ['Agency Account Bank Agreement', 'Agent', 'Reinvestment Period']
```

Comment: What problem/error do you have?

Comment: Looking at the inputs, this requires only an `in` (membership operator) check within elements of list.

Comment: You could start by defining `new_corpus`.

Comment: @Alderven I have a list with 'Agency Account Bank Agreement' and 'Agency Account Bank Agreement Pursuant' and I understand why, it's because my approach is based on the length of the words and I don't know how to remove the second word from my list and the second problem is that I have a list with multiple occurrences of the same word.

Comment: @Austin can you explain ?

Comment: Not sure if this satisfies for your original inputs, but this might help: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in

Comment: @Austin I tried to use 'in' to check if a word is already in my list or not, but I'm not getting what I want

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this list:

```
numchars = ['one', 'ones', 'two', 'twos', 'three', 'threes']
```

Let's say you believe that `one` is too similar to `ones` for your taste, and you only want to keep one of the two, such that your revised list would be similar to this:

```
numchars = ['ones', 'twos', 'threes']
```

You could do this to eliminate the ones you deem too similar:

```
for x in numchars:
    if any(lower_threshold < jellyfish.jaro_distance(x, _x) and x != _x for _x in numchars):
        numchars.remove(x)
```

Depending on the thresholds you set, as well as the order of your list, this could produce results like this:

```
numchars = ['ones', 'twos', 'threes']
```

The main logic in this routine is in this line:

```
if any(lower_threshold < jellyfish.jaro_distance(x, _x) and x != _x for _x in numchars):
```

This says if any member of the list `numchars`, when compared to all members of that list exluding itself, has a similarity rating greater than your defined `lower_threshold`, that member should be removed from the list, as such:  `numchars.remove(x)`. Also, the `and x != _x` condition avoids registering a member as being too similar to itself.

But the meat of this sandwich, so to speak, is in this line:

```
numchars.remove(x)
```

This statement ensures that once you remove `one` for being too similar to `ones`, that during the next iteration `one` isn't a member of the list anymore and isn't compared to `ones` in such a way that would remove `ones` as well. That approach would end up resulting in an empty list.

Once you start wanting to only keep pluralizations, or other certain forms of similar match-groups, you open a whole other can of worms.